# use variable as integer in GA tool box

Tags: matlab

I am solving an optimization problem for the optimal placement of piezoelectric patches over a cantilevered plate using GA tool box in MATLAB2009b.

There is a variable which varies from 1 to 64. I want the GA to take this variable as an integer only, and not as a real number because due to real number having time period for one run increases. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you basically want to round off the number? if yes, `int8(number)` or `round(number)` will do this

Comment: i ve done it. when i was using the constraint based on floor command than it gives the results based on lower bound i.e. 1 always.